# How to make a POST request in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, post, request, betfair

i. I am using visual studio 8 using vb.net. I am trying to make a post request that complies with the following schema, but am failing miserably.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<postBetOrder xmlns="urn:betfair:games:api:v1"
marketId="2568540" round="1" currency="GBP">
<betPlace>
<bidType>BACK</bidType>
<price>2.5</price>
<size>2.50</size>
<selectionId>658440</selectionId>
</betPlace>
```

I am not sure what I need to do to post to make the bet.I have had many goes at posting what  thought was the correct information in the correct form, using
    postStream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length)
But thus far all I get is an error, premature end of file.
Please can anyone help. Thanks for all contributions.

Comment: Looks like you didn't close the postBetOrder tag?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Sonny Boy, you have neglected to include a  at the end of the file.

(Community Wiki, just trying to get this question officially answered.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<postBetOrder xmlns="urn:betfair:games:api:v1"
marketId="2568540" round="1" currency="GBP">
<betPlace>
<bidType>BACK</bidType>
<price>2.5</price>
<size>2.50</size>
<selectionId>658440</selectionId>
</betPlace>
*</postBetOrder>*
```

This is the correct format to your example, but i need more information to give you a complete solution.